# Why does my mouse slow down in Paint.NET?

Tags: paint.net

I used to love Paint.NET. But when I installed a recent version of it (v3.36) in a VMware Fusion v2.0.1 Win2003 R2 machine, I have founded that my mouse slows down in the image area of the application. It's a consistent slowdown that goes away when the mouse is over a tool window or the chrome of the application.

I run a lot of software and have never seen this slowdown before. I run .NET apps, WPF apps, Flash apps, DirectX apps - none of them demonstrate the slowdown like Paint.NET. *What could it be about Paint.NET's client region that would cause this?*

**Environment**

- Machine: MacBook 13" running VMware Fusion v2.0.1
- OS: Win2003 R2

**Update**

I've posted this as a question to their support forum: http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=30845

Comment: I also have 3.36 and I don't have that behavior of the mouse; same speed all over the place.

Comment: Have you tried asking on their forum? http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/index.php

Comment: I consider slowing down the mouse in the image area very useful...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps there's no option to disable this feature because it's not actually there. I'm running v3.36 on my PC here and I just ran it to confirm that it's not slowing the mouse movement down in the way you describe.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I will revise the question to ask what could be causing it.